# Get the condition caught in a if with multiple or conditions (python)

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm just wondering if there's a way/function to get the **index** of the condition in a "if" with multiple conditions.

For example:

```
fruit = "apple"
if (fruit == "pear") or (fruit == "banana") or (fruit == "apple") or (fruit == "lemon"):
    print(index)
```

**In this case, the index printed would be 2**, because the condition with which it has entered the if, is (fruit == "apple").

Comment: Nope, you'll have to write it differently, such as `['pear', 'banana', 'apple', 'lemon'].index(fruit)`

Comment: `fruits = ["pear", "banana", "apple", "lemon"]; fruits.index(fruit)` -> 2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me change your code a little bit pythonic;

```
fruit = "apple"
all_fruits = ["pear", "banana", "apple", "lemon"]

if fruit in all_fruits:
    print(all_fruits.index(fruit))
    print(all_fruits[all_fruits.index(fruit)])
```